How to lock navigation with MMB and MMB+SHIFT in Viewport in selected area like Toggle Quad View?
I am new to Blender and have a couple of questions.

How can I block navigation with MMB and MMB+SHIFT in Viewport in a selected area (split area)?
And how can I make it so that the conditional ‘Object Mode’ I selected remains in this area and does not change to ‘Sculpt Mode’ synchronously with the right area? I wanted to make an unchanging reference area for my model, giving it the exact angle of view. To give you a better understanding of what I'm specifically looking for, I'm looking for a way to lock the rotation and change the camera position as done in the three ‘Toggle Quad View’ windows (CTRL+ALT+Q). Thank you in advance for your reply


What do you mean block navigation? Do you mean you wanted to not work? What else are you using middle mouse button for? What do you mean, in a selected area? Viewport navigation already doesn’t transfer between two different GUI Areas.

I don’t see how changing 3-D Viewport modes affects what angle a single viewport is viewing from, but 3-D viewport modes are synced across the file. I also don’t understand why you’re asking for a method of navigation which you yourself state already exists. Is your keyboard broken? You can also access the orthographic viewpoints from the View menu, or clicking the nodes of the axis Gizmo.

Are you aware of the official Blender Manual on the docs page?

@TheLabCat Yes, I know about the official Blender Manual. Looking at the attached screenshot, I'd like to make it so that I can't accidentally use the mouse and mess up the angle I've set on the left side of the screen. I'd also like to have conditional ‘Object Mode’ on the left and ‘Sculpt Mode’ on the right.
https://imgur.com/a/jERxUwK

So you're not able to have different viewports be in different modes. That's just how Blender works.
But you can achieve this camera effect you're looking for something like this:
Set up a camera in the window you want to stay locked in, get the angle you want and then lock the Location and Rotation transforms in the N-panel.

Then in the same N-panel under "View" set the camera to be the Local active Camera in that window. Now whenever you hover over this window and press Numpad0 it will align the view to that camera regardless of what camera is the active one in the scene.
Then once you've pressed Numpad0 and you're viewing the scene through that
camera get the zoom level you want and then set the "Camera to View" setting, which, if you're in that camera will mean you can't move your view at all.

Then turn off the overlays in that viewport with this button.

End result:

It would make sense to do all this in a custom workspace just one time, then you can save that to your startup file and it will always be that way in that workspace.

